# Bootstrap grid column not working as expected on sm and xs device

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The row has 4 images, it is showing 4 images in the row as expected.
On sm and xs devices it should show 4 images in a grid of 2 x 2 (two column and two rows but the third image is not aligning properly it is way off the grid.

https://jsfiddle.net/fjqcb2h6/

```html
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="row countdown-row" style="margin-bottom: 60px;">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <figure style="max-width: 100%;">
          <img onclick="Javascript: window.open('#');" class="img-fluid hvr-grow" style="width:130px;cursor:pointer;" src="images/computer.png">
          <figcaption style="padding-top: 20px; font-size: 16px;"><a href="#" target="_blank">dsfdsfdsfdsf</a></figcaption>
      </figure>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <figure style="max-width: 100%;">
          <img onclick="Javascript: window.open('#');" class="img-fluid hvr-grow" style="cursor:pointer; width:115px;" src="images/edu.png">
          <figcaption class="img-fluid" style="padding-top: 10px; font-size: 16px;"><a href="#" target="_blank">dsfsfsdfsdfdsfsdf</a></figcaption>
      </figure>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <figure style="max-width: 100%;">
          <img onclick="Javascript: window.open('#');" class="img-fluid hvr-grow" style="cursor:pointer; width:120px;" src="images/kidz.png">
          <figcaption style="padding-top: 10px; font-size: 16px;"><a href="http://#"target="_blank">sdfdsfsd</a></figcaption>
      </figure>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <figure style="max-width: 100%;">
          <img onclick="Javascript: window.open('http://#');" class="img-fluid hvr-grow" style="cursor:pointer; width:115px;" src="images/mindacti.png">
          <figcaption style="padding-top: 10px; font-size: 16px;"><a href="#">dsfdsfsdfActivation</a></figcaption>
      </figure>
  </div>

</div> <!-- row end -->
```

Comment: You missed `<div class="container">` . It should be the wrapper of your divs .

Comment: Use height property in the child elements.

Answer (score 0):

Add following style

```
.countdown-row {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the different height of the elements.

[image]

Applying height to the columns child (`<figure>` in this case) will fix the problem.
Note that height must be equal or greater than highest column child.

```
figure {
  height: 200px;
}
```

[image]